# Google App Script - Address Unavailable - Wait and try again?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have a script on Google Apps that pulls in data from a CSV, but sometimes I get an email notification that the address is unavailable. Is it possible to add a loop of some sort so that if it fails it just waits XX seconds and tries again?

```
function GetItemsCategories(){
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Global-Stock-Levels");

var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Items-Categories");
// Items
var POS = "https://pos.elqdecigs.co.uk/scripts/get-items.php?argument1=xxxx&argument2=xxxx"
sheet.getRange("A:E").clear();
var downloadCsv = UrlFetchApp.fetch(POS);
var csvData = CSVToArray(downloadCsv, ",");
for ( var i=0, lenCsv=csvData.length; i<lenCsv; i++ ) {
sheet.getRange(i+1, 1, 1, csvData[i].length).setValues(new Array(csvData[i]));
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
function getItemsCategories(){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var ish=ss.getSheetByName("Items-Categories");
  ish.clearContents();
  var POS="https://pos.elqdecigs.co.uk/scripts/get-items.php?argument1=xxxx&argument2=xxxx"
  ish.getRange(1,1,sh.getLastRow(),5).clear();
  var resp=UrlFetchApp.fetch(POS);
  var csvData=Utilities.parseCsv(resp.getContentText());
  if(csvData) {
    ish.getRange(1,1,csvData.length,csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);
    if(isTrigger('getItemsCategories')){
      deleteTrigger('getItemsCategories');
    }
  }else{
    if(isTrigger('getItemsCategories')){
      deleteTrigger('getItemsCategories');
     }
    createTrigger();
  }
}

function createTrigger() {
  if(!isTrigger('getItemsCategories')) {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger('getItemsCategories').timeBased().after(60000).create();
  }
}
```

Helper functions:

```
function deleteTrigger(triggerName){
  var triggers=ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
  for (var i=0;i<triggers.length;i++){
    if (triggerName==triggers[i].getHandlerFunction()){
      ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(triggers[i]);
    }
  }
}

function isTrigger(funcName){
  var r=false;
  if(funcName){
    var allTriggers=ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
    for(var i=0;i<allTriggers.length;i++){
      if(funcName==allTriggers[i].getHandlerFunction()){
        r=true;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  return r;
}
```

This does work I just tested something very similar to it.